# Post more entries to an email

Tags: php

I have the following PHP for sending a contact form:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['email'] && $_POST['message'])
    {
        $companyname = $_POST['company-name'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "";
        $subject = "New Message From: $name";
        $message .= "$messege";
        $headers = "From: $email";

        $mailed = ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) );

        if( isset($_POST['ajax']))
            $response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
        else
            $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" : "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";

        echo $response;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Form data error!";
    }
?>
```

in the "`$message .= "$messege";`" I believe that what will be sent and viewed in the email client right? How can I add the area code, phone number and country as well as the message?

Comment: You MUST put an isset() on $_POST['email'] and $_POST['message'] aswell by the way :-). To concatinate a string you can do this: $message = $message . ' area code: ' . $areacode . ' phone number: ' . $phone;

Comment: Why is that @CBergau I am new to this sorry.

Comment: Because when you use && in an if-condition it looks if $_POST['email'] is true. This can be very tricky. You want to assure that $_POST['email'] is really set. You do it with 'name' too.

Comment: Can you please show me how I can add isset? when you say On $_POST['email'] for example

Comment: if (isset($_POST['...']) && isset($_POST['...']) && isset($_POST['..'])

Comment: And another thing, you dont need to put "(" and ")" in the mail function. mail() does already return a boolean value. $mailed = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45050/discussion-between-leo-and-cbergau)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i post the full code to wrap things up:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $companyname = $_POST['company-name'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = "support@loaidesign.co.uk";
    $subject = "New Message From: $name";
    $message = "$message\nArea Code: $areacode\nPhone Number: $phone\n";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    $mailed = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
        $response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
    } else {
        $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" : "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
    }

    echo $response;
} else {
    echo "Form data error!";
}
```

Comment: \n basically mean a new line? is there a place I can go to find these things that I can use to format the email? Thank you for the post!

Comment: Yes this means new line.

Comment: Please can you direct me to somewhere where I can find more of these? How to style the text and the email in general - I tried to Google it but seems like I am using the wrong keywords. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply concat the message string with the info you want to add:

```
$message = "From: $name\n\n$message\n\nPhone: $phone, Country: $country, ...";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: cc@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

// check http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

$new_message = $message;
$new_message .= $areacode.$phone;

$mailed = ( mail($to,$subject,$new_message,$headers) );
```